# Problem with 'Unknown image file format' error for GCS image in Tensorflow style transfer demo

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage

I'm wanting to use my own images for this Tensorflow Style Transfer demo, which I've copied to my own Colab notebook.

[https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization][1]

I have images stored in a GCS bucket but have been getting image format errors. To test this, I took one of the images from the Tensorflow demo, downloaded it and put it in my GCS bucket, added the link to the "Let's try it on more images" section of my demo code, and am getting the same file format error message I was previously getting with my own images.

Here's where I've inserted the GCS version of the image:

```
content_urls = dict(
  tueblingen02='https://storage.cloud.google.com/01_bucket-02/Tuebingen_Neckarfront-vox.jpeg',
  sea_turtle='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Green_Sea_Turtle_grazing_seagrass.jpg',
  tuebingen='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Tuebingen_Neckarfront.jpg',
  grace_hopper='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/grace_hopper.jpg',
  )
style_urls = dict(
  kanagawa_great_wave='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/The_Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa.jpg',
  kandinsky_composition_7='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Vassily_Kandinsky%2C_1913_-_Composition_7.jpg',
```

etc ...

The resulting error message:

`InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required. [Op:DecodeImage]`

Full message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-3ded16359898> in <module>()
     26 content_image_size = 384
     27 style_image_size = 256
---> 28 content_images = {k: load_image(v, (content_image_size, content_image_size)) for k, v in content_urls.items()}
     29 style_images = {k: load_image(v, (style_image_size, style_image_size)) for k, v in style_urls.items()}
     30 style_images = {k: tf.nn.avg_pool(style_image, ksize=[3,3], strides=[1,1], padding='SAME') for k, style_image in style_images.items()}

3 frames
<ipython-input-16-3ded16359898> in <dictcomp>(.0)
     26 content_image_size = 384
     27 style_image_size = 256
---> 28 content_images = {k: load_image(v, (content_image_size, content_image_size)) for k, v in content_urls.items()}
     29 style_images = {k: load_image(v, (style_image_size, style_image_size)) for k, v in style_urls.items()}
     30 style_images = {k: tf.nn.avg_pool(style_image, ksize=[3,3], strides=[1,1], padding='SAME') for k, style_image in style_images.items()}

<ipython-input-2-1485a3082999> in load_image(image_url, image_size, preserve_aspect_ratio)
     19   img = tf.io.decode_image(
     20       tf.io.read_file(image_path),
---> 21       channels=3, dtype=tf.float32)[tf.newaxis, ...]
     22   img = crop_center(img)
     23   img = tf.image.resize(img, image_size, preserve_aspect_ratio=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7184 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7185   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7186   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7187 
   7188 

InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required. [Op:DecodeImage]
```

So that's confusing me because the image works fine when it's hosted elsewhere, leading me to believe it's not an image format issue, but something else.

I'd greatly appreciate any input or suggestions on what might be happening here.
thx

Comment: Following the tutorial I tried to reproduce this on my end and I'm having errors with the tuebingen and grace_hopper images, only the sea_turtle image worked. Did you not get any error in those two images? What version of Tensorflow are you using? Also, I downloaded the sea_turtle image and uploaded it to my GCS bucket with public access and did not get any errors. Can you do the same? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks @MabelA. Appreciate your input. I tried the sea turtle, and got a different error message this time. `Exception: URL fetch failure on =https://storage.cloud.google.com/01_bucket-02/Green_Sea_Turtle_grazing_seagrass-02.jpeg: None -- unknown url type: =https` . I don't understand how it could be the `https`, as it's working fine if I remove that on uploaded image, and use the other https images from the demo. I'm using `TF Version:  2.8.0`. When selecting the URL to post, I'm using the 'Authenticated URL'. Does that sound correct?

Comment: What changes have you done? I reproduced this again and I was able to get the `InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required. [Op:DecodeImage]` error but not your new error with `=https`. Can you download the `Green_Sea_Turtle_grazing_seagrass.jpg` again, this time save the image in your local with the exact same filename and extension from the original URL then upload it to GCS. Doing this solved the issue on my end.

Comment: Thanks @MabelA. Good suggestion, so I downloaded the file to my local drive, then uploaded it to GCS using the Authenticated URL. So the only difference between the demo version and mine is the URL for the key 'sea_turtle'. And I'm getting the same original error: `InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required. [Op:DecodeImage]`. I guess I'll have to try with every image in their model - not sure how else to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Not sure why are you getting a different behavior. On my end, I tried different scenarios: 1) Saved the image with a different filename 2) Saved the image with a different extension 3) Saved the image with the same filename at extension. Scenario 3 worked fine. Both scenario 1 and 2 failed with `InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required. [Op:DecodeImage]` error.

Comment: Thanks @MabelA. Of your tests, why do you think #1 failed. Assuming the file name you used didn't violate any naming requirements, any thoughts as to why it wouldn't accept a different file name with the correct file type extension? I don't see how that could cause an `unknown image file format` error.

Comment: I am actually not sure why it would error out even if the extension is correct. The error I got for using `.jpeg` instead `.jpg` is an expected behavior, but not for having a different filename. By the way I also tried changing the access for the files and having it public or private will not matter, both will work as long as you used the correct filename and extension.

Comment: @MabelA. That's interesting about public v private. I changed my other files to private, but I guess it's all about having the right authorization settings, which I'm still trying to get down.