# InvalidArgumentError in training loop with custom model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently experimenting with face recognition and built a model using Tensorflow and Keras, it worked perfectly fine and now I am back after a few weeks and get an error I cannot seem to fix.

This is the cell where the error pops up when I run the function with train_data:

```
def train_model(data, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS):
  """
  Loops over all batches for `epochs` and applies the `train_step()` to every element in the batch 
  """
 
  for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
    print("\n Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch, epochs))
    progbar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(len(data))

    # loop through each batch 

    for idx, batch in enumerate(data):
      # run train step 
      train_step(batch)
      
      progbar.update(idx+1)

    # save checkpoints 
    if epochs % 10 == 0:
      checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)
```

train data is formatted like this:

```
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 100, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 100, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

and the error occuring is the following InvalidArgumentError:

```
<ipython-input-63-999b29e9cecb> in train_model(data, epochs)
     11     # loop through each batch
     12 
---> 13     for idx, batch in enumerate(data):
     14       # run train step
     15       train_step(batch)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in __next__(self)
    764   def __next__(self):
    765     try:
--> 766       return self._next_internal()
    767     except errors.OutOfRangeError:
    768       raise StopIteration

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    750           self._iterator_resource,
    751           output_types=self._flat_output_types,
--> 752           output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
    753 
    754       try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py in iterator_get_next(iterator, output_types, output_shapes, name)
   3015       return _result
   3016     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 3017       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   3018     except _core._FallbackException:
   3019       pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7162 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7163   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7164   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7165 
   7166 

InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
     [[{{node DecodeJpeg_1}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

thank you in advance for your help

if more code is needed I am happy to provide it.

EDIT:

here the preprocessing code

```
# define image size variable 
IMG_SIZE = 100

# create a function to preprocess the images 
def preprocess_images(file_path, img_size=IMG_SIZE):
  """
  Takes an image filepath and preprocesses the image 
  """
  # Read the file 
  image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)

  # turn image into tensor 
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)

  # normalize the image 
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

  # resize the image to needed image size 
  image = tf.image.resize(image, size=[img_size, img_size])

  # output image 
  return image
```

Comment: Your error states that you need to use one of JPEG, PNG, GIF or BMP. Are you using another type of image ?

Comment: no I am using jpeg as image format but the images are preprocessed before getting to this step. At this point the whole data should already be in tensors

Comment: Could you provide the code where you preprocess your image and your main ? Or else it might have something to do with only one of your file being the wrong extension or corrupted. Look at this answer, maybe it'll help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192520/8228122

Comment: Let me know if it works. If it doesn't, post your preprocessing code and your main code, so I can help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191448/unknown-image-file-format-one-of-jpeg-png-gif-bmp-required)

Comment: @Luke B thanks. running the code rn and afterwards imma hit you up

Comment: Code didn't throw any warnings so the files seem to be ok. I put the preprocessing code above for you to see. Hit me up if you need anything else

Comment: After looking more in depth at your error, it seems the problem comes from the loop in enumerate, which is weird. Are you running your code locally ? And are your images local or in the cloud ? Someone seemed to have the same kind of error using google cloud storage (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71314872/problem-with-unknown-image-file-format-error-for-gcs-image-in-tensorflow-style).

Comment: @LukeB i am running the code on google colab with the data being in google drive. Might explain why it is not working cuz it was working 4 weeks ago when i initially did the project. 
Might be that some update messed up the enumerate loop. 

Thank you for your help mate

Comment: That might be it then. Good luck. Happy to help.